# Asking whether the user meant MAC or Mac

Tags: feature-request

When typing a question containing `MAC`, there should be question for the user whether he/she meant `Mac/Macintosh`. E.g. this question: [how to connect Macintosh on LAN](https://superuser.com/questions/417085/how-to-connect-macintosh-on-lan) had `MAC` all over the place before it was corrected to `Macintosh`.

Comment: See this awesome feature request on MSO: [A real solution to ambiguous tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags)

Comment: Solution:  Use the tag [tag:mac-address] for MAC-related questions, and [tag:iMac] for Macintosh hardware questions (software should all be under [tag:OSX]).  Then again, just one man's opinion, as there's thousands of questions already tagged [tag:mac]...

Comment: The issue isn't how a well informed poster to distinguish between these, but how to make uninformed posters do that.

Comment: @Breakthrough [iMac](http://www.apple.com/imac/) is a specific line of all-in-one desktop computers, positioned between Mac mini and Mac Pro. `mac` is the general tag for Apple-branded computers.